# При записи в файл очень много null characters в начале

Tags: php, null

Пишу зашифрованные AES(Rijndael) 256-bit CBC данные по схеме flock/ftruncate/fwrite/flock.
По какой-то причине при перезаписи существующего файла появляются null-character'ы в начале. Код записи:

```
/*...*/
/**
 * @param string $encrypt encrypted data to store
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function write($encrypt) {
    flock($this->handler, LOCK_EX);
    ftruncate($this->handler, 0);
    $res = fwrite($this->handler, $encrypt);
    flock($this->handler, LOCK_UN);
    return $res;
}
/*...*/
```

Вопрос: как от них избавиться?

Comment: вы уверены, что сами данные не приходят как массив null-символов?

Comment: @Etki да, уверен, все проверено

Comment: Еще что-нибудь может писать в файл?

Comment: @Etki нет, не может. я решил, смотри ниже)

Comment: хм, думал truncate сам этим занимается

Comment: @Etki очевидно, нет.
к слову, этот случай можно посмотреть [тут](http://gitlab.guava.by/izumrud/phpdb/tree/master/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил.
Нужно было сделать `rewind()`:

```
/**
 * @param string $encrypt encrypted data to store
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function write($encrypt) {
    flock($this->handler, LOCK_EX);
    ftruncate($this->handler, 0);
    rewind($this->handler);
    $res = fwrite($this->handler, $encrypt);
    flock($this->handler, LOCK_UN);
    return $res;
}
```